# How to resolve pip version conflict error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

please excuse the repeated question but the answers from similar threads haven't resolved this issue

I have been using pip with no issues for 2-3 months now but after trying to pip install pyzmail I recieved an importlib._bootstrap error message which I cannot recreate anymore but his error message has now turned into

I am recieving this error message when simply typing the pip command

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 584, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 901, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 792, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 20.1.1 (/Users/conorladrigan/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==20.0.2'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3261, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3245, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3274, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 586, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 599, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 787, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==20.0.2' distribution was not found and is required by the application```

Thanks for any help
````

Comment: Have you tried updating `pip`? What version are you using?

Comment: I have but recieve the following error message ERROR: Invalid requirement: '–upgrade' after running command python -m pip install –upgrade pip as suggested by @Robot7x

Comment: It should be `--upgrade`, with _two_ dashes

Comment: sorry that was a typo on my part . I am still receiving this error message ERROR: Invalid requirement: '–-upgrade' using two dashes

Comment: Mmmm this works for me: `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`. Just ran it and upgraded to pip-20.1.1

Comment: okay so that command worked and I received the message `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages`  but typing the pip command is still giving me the same error message as in the OP

Comment: Are you not using virtual environments (or similar tools) ? It might help alleviate these kinds of issues.

Comment: Ah, wait, that package requires that your pip version be _exactly_ 20.0.2, but your version is newer. BTW, when trying to install with `pip3 install pyzmail` without any virtual environment, I'm also getting `AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'` as you were saying earlier in the post. I'd say this package is broken. You could try downloading and installing it manually. Then you'd know where exactly the error is coming from and could edit the installation script.

Comment: No . I'm admittedly quite new to python and programming in general so I haven't been using virtual environments or any additional tools @AMC

Comment: Okay. That makes sense. The actual module itself isn't so important for me so I can work around that . Is it possible to fix pip so I can continue using the pip command going forward. Just to note , pip3 command seems to be working fine . You've been very helpful so far @Forcebru

Comment: You should be using `pip3` (not `pip`) with Python 3 anyway. It's not broken, it's just newer than what the package expects. That's why I suggested editing its installation script (`setup.py`) or `requirements.txt` maybe: you could find and remove this restriction. Or downgrade pip on your machine, maybe using a virtual environment (google "python virtual environment") so that you don't mess up the system pip

Comment: Okay . I'll proceed with pip3 going forward. I've found a more up to date version of pyzmail , pyzmail36, which seems to be working. Your time and help is much appreciated @ForceBru

Answer (score 4):

you can upgrade your pip version to the latest with

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: When running this command I am receiving the following error ERROR: Invalid requirement: '–upgrade'

Comment: @ConorLadrigan - there was a dash missing, shall be `--upgrade` (or `-U`)